# mapping operation for heterogenous List

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

I have a simple heterogenous List

```
data HList (ts :: [Type]) where
    HNil :: HList '[]
    (:&:) :: t -> HList ts -> HList (t ': ts)

infixr 5 :&:
```

and am trying to define a heterogeneous map:

```
type family ToDomain (xs :: [Type]) :: [Type] where
    ToDomain '[] = '[];
    ToDomain ((a -> b) ': r) = a ': ToDomain r

type family ToCoDomain (xs :: [Type]) :: [Type] where
    ToCoDomain '[] = '[];
    ToCoDomain ((a -> b) ': r) = b ': ToCoDomain r

mapH :: forall mappings input output.
    (input ~ ToDomain mappings, output ~ ToCoDomain mappings)
    => HList mappings -> HList input -> HList output
mapH HNil HNil = HNil
mapH (f :&: maps) (x :&: ins) = (f x) :&: mapH maps ins
```

this does not compile (i would be really surprised if this would actually work) since GHC can't infer the correctness of the recursion. I am unsure how to convince GHC of the correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove that `mappings` only has functions inside. This can be made with an additional GADT.

```
data OnlyFunctions (ts :: [*]) where
   FNil :: OnlyFunctions '[]
   FCons :: OnlyFunctions ts -> OnlyFunctions ((a->b) ': ts)

mapH :: forall mappings input output.
    (input ~ ToDomain mappings, output ~ ToCoDomain mappings)
    => OnlyFunctions mappings -> HList mappings -> HList input -> HList output
mapH FNil HNil HNil = HNil
mapH (FCons h) (f :&: maps) (x :&: ins) = (f x) :&: mapH h maps ins
```

The issue is that `ToDomain '[Int,Bool]` is a valid type -- even if `ToDomain` does not simplify in such case. Hence GHC can not assume that the `mappings` list of types is made of functions, only.

You can remove the additional argument through a custom type class, if needed.

```
class OF (ts :: [*]) where
   onlyFun :: OnlyFunctions ts
instance OF '[] where
   onlyFun = FNil
instance OF ts => OF ((a -> b) ': ts) where
   onlyFun = FCons onlyFun

mapHsimple :: forall mappings input output.
    (input ~ ToDomain mappings, output ~ ToCoDomain mappings, OF mappings)
    => HList mappings -> HList input -> HList output
mapHsimple = mapH onlyFun
```

Comment: thank you, that works and provides a way to other problems I was facing. But I think the class `OF` is wrong (HNil doesn't have kind `[*]`). I am a bit unsure how to fix the class.

Comment: @Leander Fixed the last snippet.

Comment: thank you. I didn't call onlyFun, which was my problem. Hmm needing to call onlyFun is making this technique hard to generalize.

Comment: @Leander The user of `mapHsimple` does not have to call it, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want mapping operations, you're almost certainly better off defining

```
data Rec (f :: k -> *) (ts :: [k]) where
  RNil :: Rec f '[]
  (:&:) :: f t -> Rec f ts -> Rec f (t ': ts)

infixr 5 :&:
```

Now you can define a general

```
rmap :: (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Rec f ts -> Rec g ts
```

and

```
rzipWith :: (forall a. f a -> g a -> h a) -> Rec f ts -> Rec g ts -> Rec h ts
```

This generally makes things rather easier. In this case, you could use

```
data Fun :: * -> * where
  Fun :: (a -> b) -> Fun (a -> b)

data Dom :: * -> * where
  Dom :: a -> Dom (a -> b)

data Cod :: * -> * where
  Cod :: b -> Cod (a -> b)
```

Now you can write

```
zoop :: Rec Fun fs -> Rec Dom fs -> Rec Cod fs
zoop = rzipWith (\(Fun f) (Dom x) -> Cod (f x))
```

In fact, some of this is slight overkill; you should be able to get away with a newtype wrapping a type family for `Dom`. You could even do so for `Cod`, but that might make the result less usable.